# Reproduce color palette from an image containing that color palette (IVIS machine)

Tags: python, r, colors, palette

I would like to know if that is possible to reproduce a color palette from an image.

Here is an [example](https://resources.perkinelmer.com/lab-solutions/resources/docs/tch_010887_01_subject_rois.pdf). Pages 1 and 3 show a rainbow palette in the figure legend.

The software is proprietary and has very little room for customization. I would like to regenerate the legend by R (or any other programming language, e.g. python) but retain the scale/ range of the colors.

I recognize that some color picker [tools](https://imagecolorpicker.com/) are available. However, the resolution of the palette is quite low, and often 3-4 colors are displayed in the same row. I am not sure which color I should pick in the raster image.

Answer (score 1):

Base `R` has a `rainbow` palette, which is similar to what is shown in the linked PDF

A better option might be the `turbo` color map in the `viridis` [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/viridis/vignettes/intro-to-viridis.html#the-color-scales), which transitions more gradually across the visible spectrum.

This [PDF](https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/sites/default/files/2020-04/colorPaletteCheatsheet.pdf) is a great general reference to colors in R, and may help you construct the gradient you're aiming to replicate.

In `ggplot2`, you can create these sorts of palettes using `scale_gradient` ([link](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_gradient.html)).

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

  ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), disp, fill = mpg)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c(muted('red'), 'red', 'yellow1'))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, I also want the "YellowHot" palette from them in addition to the more common rainbow palette. An example is [here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Visualization-of-ICG-fluorescence-A-ICG-is-readily-visualized-with-a-commercially_fig5_340586041). I cannot find a palette that is from "brown" to "yellow".

Comment: I've edited the answer to include one way to construct custom gradient palettes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenCV (cv2) library and export the color data as a histogram. It's also possible to apply a mask to a certain area of the image to extract the color data from that part.

For examples/documentation you can find more here: [Histograms - 1 : Find, Plot, Analyze](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d1/db7/tutorial_py_histogram_begins.html) and this one might suite you a bit more where it shows how to create 2D histograms: [Histograms - 3 : 2D Histograms](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d0d/tutorial_py_2d_histogram.html)

Hope this helps!